# Compare 2 columns using wildcards

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 columns

```
Column 1:
long hairs
hai
hello hairs
long neck

Column 2:
long
hair
```

I'm using the following formula, but it doesn't work:

```
=COUNTIF(A1;"*"&$P$1:$P$2&"*")
```

What I have to do is to be able to select somehow the cells from column 1 (it has phrases in each cell) that contain value from another range (using wildcards). I cannot use somthing like {"*hair*","*long*"} - I need it to be range.

Please advice, I have searched here a lot, but nothing seemed to work.
If it is relevant - I'm using cyrllic words and phrases in these columns.

Comment: I posted an answer, but after doing so, I see what you write is that you want to  `select` certain cells. A formula cannot `select` a cell.  If that is what you really want to do, you will need a VBA solution.  Do you want to do anything with the cells after you select them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The countif formula, using a range as the criteria, will return an array of values.  So you need to SUM the results.  e.g:

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A1,"*" & P1:P2 & "*"))
```

confirmed by holding down `ctrl+shift` while hitting `enter`.

Or, entered normally:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1,"*" & P1:P2 & "*"))
```

With the data in column A, the criteria in Column C, and the formula in Column B, using this variation:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1,"*"&$C$1:$C$2&"*"))
```

We see the following for a result:

[image]

Comment: I actually need just any solution to be able to differ those phrase where the match exists. However your solution didn't work for me. In cells A1-A7 I have the following: hairs, hair, long hairs, hello hairs, hello long, hello hello, hello omg. In C1-C2 I have: hair, long. In B1 I paste:`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A13;"*"&B1:B2&"*"))` then I drag it down and get in B1-B7 this: 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2

Comment: @EdgardGomezSennovskaya  What is in `A13`? that you reference in your formula?

Comment: It's A1, I typed "3" accidentally

Comment: @EdgardGomezSennovskaya What would you expect?  And, if you are going to fill down, you need to make the C1:C2 reference absolute, not relative, else it will change.  I will post a screen shot

Comment: @EdgardGomezSennovskaya In your screen shot you have hair and hello in C1:C2, so it should match all of your examples.